# How to handle tightly coupled database with automation testing

Tags: ruby, database, automation, dependencies

I'm currently working on a large Tier 1 project where we are migrating a legacy swing app to a new web based app and we are rebuilding our automation suite from the ground up. We are still utilizing the existing databases and pd code from our old system (large scale complex oracle databases and a java backend).

One issue we had with our old automation suite is that a precursor to many scenarios would be to find a participant with specific criteria which in around 10% of runs would fail because a participant didn't exist.

With our new automation suite we are looking to mitigate this issue from the get go but I'm finding a lack of solutions online.

We are using jruby with cucumber to automate our project and have pretty free flexibility with gems/tools to help with this problem.

Comment: The solution to this is to make sure all your tests do not rely on existing data. If you need to find a participant with specific criteria, you should create that user the first part of the step. You could also consider skipping the database and just creating a participant using some sort of factory and mocked database. If at all possible, avoid relying on existing data.

Comment: I think we would have to rely on something similar to the first method because a good portion of our tests being more so regression would need the participant to actual exists so we could test multi-step or even multi-day processes that wouldn't work without them being real.

Comment: There's no logical difference between test data and "real" data, except maybe where it came from (you invented it and it doesn't cover the tests well, or it's came from regression bug hunting and you put it into the tests because of a specific edge case). Either way you'd create the data as part of your test setup, placing the data into your in your test database, regardless of where the data came from.